# SVN (mf) mine-full - accept my version of entire file (even non-conflicts) doesn't make an update

Tags: svn, sftp

I'm using sftp and now I've changed the file that has been changed a lot time ago.

1. I made `commit` - the result was `Commited revision xx`.
2. I made `update`. And here is the problem. And I guess that svn has a trouble updating the file because it asked me a lot of options of resolving the conflict. I choose `mf (accept my version of entire file)`, guessed that it will overwrite older version of file. It said: `updated to revison xx`. But the file has not been changed. If I write `svn info index.php` it shows the right date and revision but the file is still old. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update SVN tries to merge your local changes into the file fetched from the repository. If you have conflicts then there are 3 options:

1. fix the merge conflicts as normal.
2. use svn revert to ignore all your local changes
3. overwrite the file with your new one and commit.

I think you want the 3rd option - start from a clean base, copy your file over, commit it. I'm not sure what you expect, or if you're description is wrong as committing and then updating will not do anything (you're updating to the latest version which is the one you just committed, obviously). If you've replaced the file and want to ignore any merging, then you want to commit it so keep your changes, not update.

Comment: You got me right - I want to overwrite old version of file with my new version.I commited it and made update. But the file didn't change...

Comment: that's right - commit sends the changes to the server. Update brings the changes from the server to your local working copy. Commit then update doesn't do anything. Read the svn redbook.

Comment: Then learn to use it, read [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html).